# probability that a person will be included in a team

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 30 players, and the final team will comprise just 10 players. What is the probability that a person makes in to the final team, given that players are selected randomly.

Isn't it same as selecting a random player from 30 players, i.e. isn't the probability that a random player will make into the final team is $\frac{1}{30}$

** after giving a bit of thought, the number of ways 10 players can be selected from 30 players in $\binom{30}{10}$, this should be the denominator. But what is the numerator ? The number of ways a single player is selected from 30 players ?

Comment: No.  $1/30$ is the chance that a player will be chosen for a team of just ONE player.  Think again.

Comment: Suppose the team had $30$ players, what is the chance then?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork does that make sense ?

Comment: Let $A$ be the particular person.
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{$A$ is included in the final team})
&=\frac{\text{# teams where $A$ is included}}{\text{total # teams}}
\\
&=\frac{\binom{29}{9}}{\binom{30}{10}}
\\
&=\frac13
\end{align}
$$
The reason that the number of teams where $A$ is included is $\binom{29}{9}$, is because in order to specify a team where $A$ is included, you need to choose the $9$ other team members from the $29$ people besides $A$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285127/177399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have with $30 \choose 10$ is how many teams of ten can be made from 30 players.
Think of it like this. What are the odds of a person being selected for the first spot: (1/30). What are the odds that someone is selected for the second spot: (1/29), since one player has alread been selected. Contiue this logic for all ten slots. You then add all of the probabilites together since the probabilites are all dependent.